# Как в CMake одновременно для CMakeLists создать 2 exe файла?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Собственно вопрос простой, стало интересно. Возможно ли в конфигурации CMakeLists указать как-то о создании двух exe для разных сурсов? (Без создания дополнительных подпроектов CMake или создания библиотек)

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? Просто вызываете еще одну функцию add_executable

Comment: ничего не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот, например:

```
add_executable(app1_target)
add_executable(app2_target)
add_library(lib_target)

// later...

target_sources(app1_target PRIVATE app1_main.cpp)
target_sources(app2_target PRIVATE app2_main.cpp)
target_sources(lib_target PRIVATE lib.cpp)
```